# Openssl_decrypt doesn't recognize the value of $_GET

Tags: php, openssl

does any one know why when I write :

```
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($given_code , $method , $password);
```

works fine , but when the

```
$given_code = $_GET['given_code'];
```

the openssl_decrypt returns nothing ??? on a php of course

Comment: `var_dump($given_code);` before the decrypt. Most likely you don't get the data you expect

Comment: what do you mean ? this is the code returned by $_GET :5J/U2MKvM6AYc+YV7LyQ6vVPgRX0bLDZKR4nmE9yC9Q=           and by var_dump = 5J/U2MKvM6AYc YV7LyQ6vVPgRX0bLDZKR4nmE9yC9Q=

Comment: now I see the error , the encrypted code contains some + signs that turn into spaces using $_GET ... any way to skip it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it out : 
it was a problem related to the url encoding , so what i did is just to urlencode the value of the code generated by openssl_encrypt before sending it to the other page